# Why does my Cypher query yield unknown error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my graph:

[image]

I wanted to run a query to find all simple paths between two ports in my graph for example if I want paths between "Bandar Abbas" and "JebelAli" I want just the below path:

"Bandar Abbas" -> "JebelAli"

not this two:

"Bandar Abbas" -> "JebelAli"
"Bandar Abbas" -> "JebelAli" -> "Soha" -> "Chang Choong" -> "JebelAli"

**So I wrote this Chypher query:**

```
MATCH path=(port1: Port { name: "Bandar Abbas" })-[:CMA*]->(port2: Port { name: "JebelAli" })
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) WHERE 1=size(filter(m in nodes(path) WHERE n=m)))
RETURN path;
```

But it gives me this error:

> key not found:   UNNAMED50
>   Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this query:

```
MATCH path=(port1: Port { name: "Bandar Abbas" })-[:CMA*]->(port2: Port { name: "JebelAli" })
WHERE size(nodes(path))=size(filter(m in nodes(path) WHERE 1=size(filter(n in nodes(path) WHERE n.name=m.name ))))
RETURN path;
```

but still I do not know why my first query gave that error!.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, if you want all simple paths, then you can do this with [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), specifically with the allSimplePaths procedure in the [graph algorithms](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) section.

An example of usage:

```
MATCH (port1: Port { name: "Bandar Abbas" }), (port2: Port { name: "JebelAli" })
call apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(port1, port2, 'CMA>', 5) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in neo4j 3.1.0 (which may be what you are using).

Here is another way to get the paths in which all nodes only appear once (i.e., the count of nodes is the same as the count of distinct nodes):

```
MATCH path=(port1: Port { name: "Bandar Abbas" })-[:CMA*]->(port2: Port { name: "JebelAli" })
WITH path, nodes(path) AS ns
WITH path, ns, COUNT(ns) AS cnt_all
UNWIND ns AS n
WITH path, cnt_all, COUNT(DISTINCT n) AS cnt_distinct
WHERE cnt_all = cnt_distinct
RETURN path;
```